# Why do we concatenate the condition vector two times in conditional variational autoencoder (CVAE)

Tags: autoencoders, variational

I don't quite understand why, in *conditional variational autoencoders* (CVAEs) we condition on both the encoder and the decoder. In particular, in CVAE the objective function is defined to be:

$$\mathcal{L}_{CVAE} = \mathbb{E}_\textbf{z}[log \, p_\theta(\textbf{x}|\textbf{z},\textbf{c})] - D_{KL}[q_\phi(\textbf{z}|\textbf{x},\textbf{c})||p(\textbf{z}|\textbf{c})]$$

Then I don't understand conceptually the sense of conditioning on inputs, then sampling from latent representation, then conditioning **again** on the sampled vector, to reconstruct the input. I mean, if we already concatenate the label vector $\textbf{c}$ at the beginning, why do we do that again on the latent representation?